# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'request' of undefined in sencha touch2 external webservice

Tags: web-services, sencha-touch

Hi i am new to sencha touch2. i have to consume external web service. i have written code as below in console it is giving error like this **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'request' of undefined**. what is the problem, please provide the solution. Thank you

```
Ext.util.JSONP.request({
    url: 'http://localhost/SLS.BRND.Services/Service1.asmx/Helloworld',
    params: {
        method: 'Helloworld',
        format: 'json',
        callback: 'callback'
    },

    success: function(response) {
        alert('Working!')
        console.log(response);
    },
    failure: function(response) {
        alert('Not working!')
        console.log(response);
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this:

```
requires: ['Ext.data.JsonP'],
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Ext.data.jsonP.request](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.JsonP)

```
Ext.data.JsonP.request({
    url: 'http://localhost/SLS.BRND.Services/Service1.asmx/Helloworld',
    params: {
        method: 'Helloworld',
        format: 'json',
        callback: 'callback'
    },

    success: function(response) {
        alert('Working!')
        console.log(response);
    },
    failure: function(response) {
        alert('Not working!')
        console.log(response);
    }
});​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/Tw7cb/)**

Hope this helps

Comment: i have used Ext.data.jsonP.request instead of Ext.util.JSONP.request. but still it is giving same error in console.  if i put Ext.Ajax.request instead of Ext.data.jsonP.request it will go to alert msg not working.can you tel me how can consume external web service in sench touch2.thank you

Comment: updated my answer, its an example that i took from sencha website, hope it helps

Comment: I am getting the following error with this code: **"Cannot call method 'request' of undefined"**. I also added **requires:['Ext.data.JsonP'],** in my app.js but I am still having the error. Any idea what could be the reason?

Comment: Sorry, It was a cache problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
Ext.data.JsonP.request({
    url: 'http://A-Valid-Domain/SLS.BRND.Services/Service1.asmx/Helloworld',
    params: {
        method: 'Helloworld',
        format: 'json',
        callback: 'callback'
    },

    success: function(response) {
        alert('Working!')
        console.log(response);
    },
    failure: function(response) {
        alert('Not working!')
        console.log(response);
    }
});​
```